# Modifying parameters through the function

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how I would go about getting the `square_each` list back without using return?

Here are the specifics: Write and test a function `square_each(nums)`, where `nums` is a (Python) list of numbers. It modifies the list nums by squaring each entry and replacing its original value. You must modify the parameter, return will not be allowed!

```
def square_each(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        nums[i]= int(nums[i]) * int(nums[i])
    return nums

def sum_list(str_list):
    x = sum(str_list)
    return x

def to_numbers(str_list):
    for i in range(len(str_list)):
        str_list[i] = eval(str_list[i])
    return str_list

def main():
    file=open("numbers.txt").readline().split(" ")
    print(to_numbers(file))
    print(square_each(file))
    print(sum_list(file))

main()
```

Comment: Check the value of `file` after you have executed the function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list comprehension` and play with how Python deals with objects. It is [neither call by value, nor call by reference](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/)

```
def square_each(num_list):
    intermediate_list = [x**2 for x in num_list]
    num_list.clear()  # Removes all the elements of current list
    num_list.extend(intermediate_list)  # Adds processed elements to the original list
```

Here you need to modify the list in-place.

Note that it is better than using `global` or any other such stuff, since it prevents the introduction of other set of problems that may be introduced due to `global` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

The function `square_each` that you posted already fulfills your conditions:

```
def square_each(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        nums[i] = int(nums[i]) * int(nums[i])

l = [1, 2, 3]
square_each(l)
print(l)  # output: [1, 4, 9]
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to declare `nums` in global scope

So do it like this

```
nums = [] # your array in global scope

def square_each():
    # Now you can use original nums
    global nums
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        nums[i]= int(nums[i]) * int(nums[i])
```

Comment: Since the function signature is specified, and `nums` must be passed as a parameter, this doesn't satisfy the requirements, does it?